# Terminal/Bash command to recursively cat each file in directory, and store first 100 lines in text file named the same as the file selected

Tags: bash, ssh, cat

As the title says, I have a directory in a remote server with a bunch of huge files. I just want to CAT the first 100 lines of each file in the directory, and store it in a .txt file named after the huge file that was "cat'd", in a local directory. Is this possible through one command? Or is a bash script necessary?

Comment: what kind of access

Comment: The title of your question suggests a fundamental lack of understanding of what a terminal is, what bash is, and what the average command is, related to the former two.

Comment: Do you want a distinct local file per remote file, which contains the first 100 lines of the corresponding remote file? Or, the first 100 lines of each remote file are to be merged into a single local file?

Answer (score 0):

```sh
#/usr/bin/bash

remote_dir="/home/gary/dir"

local_output_dir="/home/gary/data"

dir_listing="$(ssh user@host ls -Q $remote_dir)" 

echo DIR: $dir_listing

IFS='
'

for file in $dir_listing
do 
   echo Processing $file...
   ssh -q user@host "cat "${remote_dir}/$file" | head -100" \> "${local_output_dir}/hun.$file" 
done
```

Comment: IFS=' is supposed to be followed by a new line in the code, not a \n. the \n is just there to represent the newline, remove the \n and put it over two lines. for some reason when i had the NFS=' followed by a newline char, stack posting changed it to be one line... other then that, this code works.

Comment: seems that was a pebkac error. i didn't now how to format. the format is fixed. this code works.